# dashboard not working with https - K8s Version- v1.19.6

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have deployed [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#kubernetes-dashboard) with a command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

and I've edited the Service as a Nodeport and configured Ingress object accordingly. I could able to login to dashboard with http but getting issue while login the same URL with https:

```
"TLS handshake error from 10.244.0.0:44950: remote error: tls: unknown certificate" .
```

When i configured ingress rule with ssl it is giving error:

```
"Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."
```

I have jenkins application running on same cluster with real certificate and i could able to login the jenkins url with https .

Cluster Information:
k8s cluster running on (Linux Server release 7.9)
kubernetes version (v1.19.6)
Request you to confirm if any suggestion to fix this issue

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kube-system-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - console.qa.test.com
    secretName: qa-pss-dashboard
  rules:
  - host: console.qa.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 8443
```

Comment: How about adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS` to annotations?

Comment: Also you can instruct `Ingress` do decrypt packets in backend with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true`

Comment: Are you using `HAProxy` Ingress Controller ?
Can you provide logs from the ingress controller Pod ?
After running `kubectl  describe ing kube-system-ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard` command, do you have any entries in the `Events` section ?

Comment: Yes I am using Haproxy Ingress controller . I was doing small mistake , i was using the custom certificate which i was created for jenkins application in same cluster but different namespace .Hence i followed the official document and it got worked -https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/installation.md#recommended-setup.
" kubectl create secret generic kubernetes-dashboard-certs --from-file=$HOME/certs -n kubernetes-dashboard  "
Thank you all for your valuable time ,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the annotation
ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

Please not that the kubernetes dashboard service is exposed in 443 port, not 8443 that is related to the deployment (pod port).

so:

```
    backend:
      service:
        name: kubernetes-dashboard
        port:
          number: 443
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `ingress.kubernetes.io/server-ssl: "true"` annotation instead of `ssl-passthrough: "false"`. See [the documentation](https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/documentation/annotations.md#server-ssl)